# Making a list of names within an entry on MS access

Tags: listview, ms-access

I'm making a database for co-ordinating training courses, split into three tables:

Trainers
Courses
Clients

For each entry in courses, I want a list of names for the people who will be attending, so I can make a report including a certificate for each of the trainees, but the only way I can think of doing it is making a new table for every new course, but considering the amount of courses we run, that could get messy very quickly.

Is there any way to make a new field on Courses, that will list all the people attending that course? I need it so I can produce a report with one page for each of the trainees, which has their name on it.

Answer (score 1):

You need some additional junction tables:

```
Trainers 
   ID
Courses 
   ID
Clients
   ID

TrainersCourses 
   TrainerID )  Primary key
   CourseID )

CoursesClients 
   CourseID    )  Primary key
   ClientID    )
   DateOfCourse ) (Possibly)
```

You may wish to read http://r937.com/relational.html or a similar document.